# What does /** means in js with respect to files, and not to comments

Tags: javascript, json, file, package.json

I have been stuck at a code and unable to find the meaning of `/**` common to package.json files field.
E.g. here

```
"files":[
          "./*",
          "./**",
          "icon.*"
]
```

I am unable to know the meaning of any of the element of files in the above code taken from package.json

Comment: They are called globs, you can find more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad Alfy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's directories wildcards:

`./*` - Any file in current directory.

`./**` - Any file in current directory and sub directories.

`icon.*` - Any file with name `icon`.

---

Read more about [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) from NPM documentation

Comment: Thanks @Justinas you have saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Those are known as *globs*, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob for instance:

> - `*` Matches 0 or more characters in a single path portion
> - `**` If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

Not exactly sure who created them in the very first place though to be honest.

EDIT: actually, from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)):

> The glob command, short for *global*, originates in the earliest versions of Bell Labs' [Unix](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unix).